# build libzmq on mac os x

Tags: xcode, macos, compilation, zeromq

I am trying to use ZMQ library to communicate between python and c++ code.

I downloaded the source zip from http://zeromq.org/area:download and built it for the windows by using visual studio 2010.

I need to support MAX OS X also. So I tried the same above process by using xcode.

```
-> I downloaded the code from http://zeromq.org/area:download "POSIX tarball".
-> extract content of zeromq-4.0.4.tar.gz which is downloaded in the above step
-> created the project on xcode
-> included all the files from zeromq-4.0.4/src and zeromq-4.0.4/inc in the xcode project
-> build
```

Xcode is giving an error while compiling i.e. Unsupported browser in file poller.hpp (77).

I tried to understand from the zmq website but I could not built it.

Can anybody pleas help me building the static lib for the MAC OS X

Thank you.

Comment: As of now the issue is resolved by doing some changes in the original code.
    -> Added new file in the src folder with the name platform.hpp
    -> with #define XMQ_HAVE_OSX

Answer (score 1):

As per official documentation

```
brew install zeromq
```

Answer (score 0):

On the zeromq download page that you reference:

> To build on UNIX-like systems
>
> If you have free choice, the most comfortable OS for developing with
>   ZeroMQ is probably Ubuntu.
>
> Make sure that libtool, autoconf, automake are installed. Check
>   whether uuid-dev package, uuid/e2fsprogs RPM or equivalent on your
>   system is installed. Unpack the .tar.gz source archive. Run
>   ./configure, followed by make. To install ZeroMQ system-wide run sudo
>   make install. On Linux, run sudo ldconfig after installing ZeroMQ. To
>   see configuration options, run ./configure --help. Read INSTALL for
>   more details.

Tells you pretty clearly that on Mac OS X compilation uses automake/autoconf. Instead of importing the files into Xcode, install the Xcode command-line tools and do a simple `./configure --enable-static && make` to build the static library. The configure script will generate the right headers for you. This is pretty much the default way most libraries that use automake/autoconf are built...

Comment: Hey I am not sure if uuid-dev package, uuid/e2fsprogs RPM or equivalent  is there on my OSx ! can you please help, before i make messy install.. of zeromq on my OSx 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

Just use cmake described [here](http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software):

```
git clone https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq
mkdir cmake-build && cd cmake-build
cmake .. && make -j 4
make test && make install && sudo ldconfig
```

I failed 2 test, 1 exception, the other time out.
But building is fine except ldconfig is not on Mac, so need to use dyld
(i am not sure this part)

But it seems working

P.S. Read INSTALL doesn't not give much info